# Cant get Spring profile Groups working in application.yml

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

I am trying to get spring profiles groups working, so that I can run two profiles at the same time. Apart from local which is set as default, the other 3 profiles dev, qa and prod are set by Jenkins as part of CI, using one JenkinsFile. This is my application.yml.

So there are two key profiles that need to be run at one time. @activatedProperties@ that will come in via Jenkins, this is profile is used to set all the IP wiring and plumbing used to set Eureka further down. But I also need awss3 to be set as a profile. If you dont use git  as a config repo, you have to set the  config server configuration you are using in this case awss3 as a active profile.

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: @activatedProperties@
  # activatedProperties from jenkins will come in as local by default or dev, qa, prod
    group:
      local: "awss3"
      dev: "awss3"
      qa:  "awss3"
      prod:  "awss3"
  application: 
    name: HP-FETCHER-CONFIG-SERVICE
  

  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        awss3:
          bucket: hp-fetcher-config
          region: us-west-2
          order: 1
```

I guess I am not using profiles group in the correct manner.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct way to set profile groups

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: @activatedProperties@
    group:
      local:
      - "awss3"
      dev:
      - "awss3"
  application: 
    name: HP-FETCHER-CONFIG-SERVICE
```

A word of advice stay away from Spring.cloud.config.server, its a total nightmare to get working especially in as an  ECS. It only works as a nice simple localhost.